# mathplotlib custom order for xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data for hour of day between 19:00 and 06:00 
and like to plot it in natural order on x-axis. 
That means values for x-axis will be ordered as following sequence 19, 20, 21, 23, 0, 1, 2, .. 6

How can i achieve?

This is my sample code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(19,24+6)%24
y = np.random.rand(len(x))*10

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can (a) treat the values as categories, `plt.bar(x.astype(str), y)`, (b) treat the values as datetimes, which would require to give each hour a corresponding date first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to make sure that your `x` datapoints are continuous and then reliable the `xticks` like so

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(19,24+6)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))*10

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, labels=x % 24)
plt.show()
```